# New web applications throwing 404 error in IIS 6.0 and windows 2003

Tags: iis

In my windows 2003 box, I am not able to create new web applications. My old ones are working absolutely fine.

When I create a new one, when I try to browse the same I get the below mentioned error:

```
HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
```

Comment: How are you trying to browse the site?  Through a web browser or through IIS Admin Tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe some versions of IIS may indicate "not found" when they really mean "insufficient permission". I'd double check the permissions & authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I also spent a day to troubleshoot this error.  end up Windows hide known file extension by default and test.txt actual file name was test.txt.txt. so does index.html became index.html.txt

That's why files keep on 404 not found!